# No me Carga el Navigation Drawer , No view found for id

Tags: android

Tengo un Navigation Drawer con una opción de cerrar sesión, mediante una bandera con sharedPreferences recupero los datos desde el activity, me llama solamente al fragment pero no con el Navigation Drawer, a lo que le doy click al fragment la app se cae y sale este error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0900f2
```

Este es mi código de la activity

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ProgressBar progressBar_cargando;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cargando_sesion);

        progressBar_cargando = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progressBar_cargando.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("preferenciasLogin", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        boolean BANDERA_SESSION = preferences.getBoolean("session", false);

                        if(BANDERA_SESSION){
                            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                    .replace(android.R.id.content, new ServiciosFragment()).commit();

                        }else{
                            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                    .add(android.R.id.content, new LoginFragment()).commit();
                        }
                    }
                },2000);

    }
```

ALguien que me pueda orientar, de antemano le quedo Agradecido

Comment: Tienes una posible solución [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508044/android-fragment-no-view-found-for-id)

Comment: He revisado todas soluciones en este foro, pero no me he tenido suerte

Answer (score 0):

Revisando tu código me parece que tienes el Navigation Drawer en tu layout `activity_cargando_sesion.xml` pero tratas de controlarlo desde uno de los Fragment que cargas, por esta razón obtienes que no encuentra la vista

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0900f2

Si te encuentras desde un `Fragment`, puedes hacer referencia a el `Activity` y encontrar la referencia del navigation drawer usando `getActivity().findViewById(...)`.

Ejemplo:

```
  drawerLayout = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
```